# Data frame values get integer values instead of text

Tags: r, string, dataframe, for-loop, integer

Here is my data:

```
require(HH)
data(ProfChal)
rowsCount = length(ProfChal$Question)
ProfChal$NEW = character(rowsCount)
```

It looks like this:
[image: HH ProfChal dataset]

When I run this loop:

```
for (r in 1:rowsCount){
  ProfChal[r,"NEW"] = ProfChal[r,"Subtable"]
}
```

the new column has integers in it:
[image: Results table after running for loop - integers filled in]

I would like to have *text* values instead of *integers*. Debugging it leaves me confused...

`ProfChal[2,"Subtable"]` returns `[1] Employment sector`.
`ProfChal[1,"NEW"] = "asdf"` works as expected.

Comment: I know about `df$TargetCol <- df$SourceCol`, but originally, I don't want it. I created this example loop just for simplicity.

Comment: And yet, accepted answer is doing exactly what you are doing in your comment, but with *as.character* around it.

Comment: @zx8754 - Because of the answer, I have applied *as.character* on  elements in my loop, not on full column, which was not possible using aforementioned syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the column `Subtable` is stored as a `factor` not as `character`.
You can check this by typing `class(ProfChal[ ,"Subtable"])`.

You can convert this column to character using `as.character`:

```
ProfChal[, "NEW"] = as.character(ProfChal[, "Subtable"])
```

Note also, that you do not need a for loop in this example.